# DataGridView HeaderCell doesn't show value when it's a numeric type

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Can someone explain to me why this code

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = 10;
```

shows nothing while this one

```
dataGridView1.Rows[0].HeaderCell.Value = 10.ToString();
```

works correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This looks like a sort of bug. It's actually not, but it *feels like* one when you set the property and you have different results in similar conditions.

What happens:
`[DataGridView].Rows[N].HeaderCell` is of type [DataGridViewRowHeaderCell](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.cs,26). The `FormattedValue` property doesn't belong to this class directly, it's derived from [DataGridViewHeaderCell](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewHeaderCell.cs,22) which, in turn, derives it from [DataGridViewCell](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,35) (the generic class).

The `DataGridViewHeaderCell` sets the default `FormattedValue` and `Value` types as:

```
 private static Type defaultFormattedValueType = typeof(System.String);
 private static Type defaultValueType = typeof(System.Object);
```

When we set:

```
[DataGridView].Rows[N].HeaderCell.Value = 10;
```

The Value is stored as an Object, boxing an `int`.
If we inspect the **`HeaderCell`** object right after setting the Value, we can see that the `FormattedValue` and `FormattedValueType` properties are set, respectively, to `"10"` and `System.String`.
This happens because these properties values are retrieved by the `DataGridViewCell` class, [calling its GetFormattedValue()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCell.cs,343) method.
The `FormattedValueType` property defaults to `System.String`.

So, it *looks like* this `FormattedValue` will be used when the Header content is rendered.
This doesn't happen. When the Header needs to be rendered, the `DataGridViewRowHeaderCell` sets its `FormattedValue` to the original Value (an `int`): the `FormattedValueType` is ignored. The reason is explained, in comments, in the [GetContentBounds()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.cs,304) method (and in more than one other places):

> *Intentionally not using GetFormattedValue because header cells
>   don't typically perform formatting.
>
>   The content bounds are computed on demand* [...]

For the same reason, the Row Header cell doesn't raise `CellFormatting` events.

The private [PaintPrivate()](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewRowHeaderCell.cs,751) method, which renders the Row Header cell, receives a `formattedValue` representing an `int`, not a string.

It then uses:

```
string formattedString = formattedValue as string;
```

to *convert* `formattedValue` to a string. Since `formattedValue` is not a string, the *cast* returns `null`, so no content is rendered.

The same condition, of course, applies to the [DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs.cs,15): when the **`CellPainting`** event is raised, the **`e.FormattedValue`** property returns `10` (an `int`).

It return `"10"` instead, if we set:

```
[DataGridView].Rows[N].HeaderCell.Value = "10";  // Or 10.ToString()
```

In this case, `string formattedString = formattedValue as string;` does return a string and this content is rendered.
Now that it's rendered, we can better understand why we cannot use the RowHeader Cell value to display content in this type of Cell: the content bounds are not exactly *considered* and the rendering is miserable.

To number the Rows using the Row Header, we need to handle the [CellPainting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellpainting) event.