# DataGridView Cell with an Interface Type doesn't show a Value

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I Have a DataGridView that's working just fine displaying data as follows:

```
private DataGridView dgv;
private List<Item> Items = new();
Items.Add(new() {ID = 1, Service = new() { Name = "Item 1"}, Quantity = 2});
dgv.DataSource = Items;

// [...]

Public Class Item 
{
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public Service Service {get; set;}
    public int Quantity {get; set;}
}

Public Class Service
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
    Public overrides string To string  => Name;
}
```

Everything was working just fine until I introduced

```
public interface IService 
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

And then changed:

```
public Service Service {get; set;}
```

To:

```
public IService Service {get; set;}
```

And then have the `Service` class implements the interface:

```
public class Service: IService...
```

Everything works still except that the `Service` column in the DataGridView shows nothing, although when I hover over it with mouse I can see the value

Comment: Items.Add(new() { ID = 1, Service = new Service() { Name = "Item 1" }, Quantity = 2 });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the DataGridView needs to format the value of a Cell, for presentation, it performs a (long) series of tests on the underlying Type.
It then calls the default formatter for the Type, so you can override `ToString()` in a class object, to return a formatted value.

When the underlying Type is an Interface, it verifies whether [IFormattable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iformattable) is implemented. If it's not, then the `FormattedValue` is `null`.

See also the notes here:
[DataGridView HeaderCell doesn't show value when it's a numeric type](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61048066/7444103)

---

Given the current structure:

```
public class Item {
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public IService? Service { get; set; } = null;
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class Service : IService {
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public override string ToString() => Name;
}

public interface IService {
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

You can do a couple of things:

If you need to keep the structure of the classes as it is, then handle the [CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event and set the Cell's Value to the current `e.Value` (a `Service` object), cast to string, i.e., `e.Value.ToString()`:

```
private void dgv_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e) {
    var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    if (dgv?.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == nameof(Service)) {
        e.Value = e.Value?.ToString();
    }

    // Or...
    if (e.Value?.GetType() == typeof(Service)) {
        e.Value = e.Value?.ToString();
    }
}
```

If you instead can change the Service class, then implement IFormattable. You can make its `ToString()` implementation just call the existing `ToString()` override if no other formatting is needed (e.g., you need to consider a specific Culture or Format):

```
public class Service : IService, IFormattable {
    public string Name { get; set; } = string.Empty;
    public override string ToString() => Name;
    public string ToString(string? format, IFormatProvider? provider) => ToString();
}
```

In this case, you don't need to handle `CellFormatting`.
Of course, to make the DataGridView use the IFormattable methods, you need to provide a format. Hence, after you have set the DataSource of the DataGridView, set the [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format) Property of the `Service` Column to a generic format, e.g.,:

```
dgv.Columns["Service"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "G";
```

The DataGridView has a check to verify whether the class object implements IFormattable, and calls its methods if it does.

Comment: Implementing the `IFormattable` some how didn't work, but doesn't matter, The `CellFormatting` Option worked fine. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I missed you comment for some reason. To make the `IFormattable` method work, you of course need to provide a formatting option. So, after you have set the DataSource of your DataGridView, set the Format property of the Service Column; e.g., `dgv.Columns["Service"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "G";`. I'm adding a note about it.